# Combining different videos in a script

Tags: premiere

I do a lot of 3D asset reviews with clients.

I send them over a bunch of video files to review, but I'd rather just send one video that shows off the asset from multiple angles.

Is there any software out there that could do this? I'd rather not have to manually combine the videos in Premiere all the time.

Comment: ffmpeg can do this. It's a great tool and can literally do this with one click. The caveat is that you have to set it up and create the script yourself. Not hard if you have a bit of programming or shell experience. A good challenge if you're a computer enthusiast. Very hard if you don't really like computers and all that stuff. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20430/how-to-concatenate-multiple-videos-with-ffmpeg